# How to create system that database notifies server, and then server pushes updated data to client application?

Tags: angular, angularjs, database, api, client-applications

More precisely, I'm building betting application, where coefficients are variable thing. So, the old application is making http request every 5 minutes. I see drawbacks here. For example, in that period of 5 minutes, there maybe will not be any changes and there is redundant requests, or, there will be a lot of them. So I would say, the data is not up to date most of the time. I want to ask you, is there a technology that allows database to notify server/api about changes, and when it does, server pushes the updates to client application. The old application is built on AngularJS, and I would like to build the new one on latest version of Angular ?

Answer (score 0):

Betting, financial whatever transactions if they are heavily time dependant (which sounds like your case is) will most likely end up using `websockets` in one form or the other. There are many messaging libraries out there to help you implement this where queues, load management, transactions are already integrated. With WS were talking about ms precision.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BfCnjr_Vjg